# I can't see bullet image

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create my own game for using reinforcement learning and I created this code.  But when I press <kbd>space</kbd> bar I can't see the bullet.

Can anyone help? Thanks for interest My codes is this:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
```

First I want to create my player, but I want to create my bullet image on my player class too, that's why I do this:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('warship.png').convert()
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.bullet_rect = self.image2.get_rect()
        self.bullet_rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx
        self.bullet_rect.y = self.rect.y
        self.bullet_rect_speedy = 0
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH/2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 50
        self.speedx = 0
```

Then I want to move my player and bullet together:

```
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.bullet_rect_speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.bullet_rect_speedy = -10
        else:
            self.speedx = 0

        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.bullet_rect.y += self.bullet_rect_speedy


        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        if self.bullet_rect.y <= 0:
            self.bullet_rect.y = self.rect.y

    def getCoordinates(self):
        return (self.rect.x,self.rect.y)


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

background = pygame.image.load('yeni_resim.jpg')

pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')

icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

all_sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

all_sprite.add(player)

running = True

while running:  

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    all_sprite.update()
    all_sprite.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        pygame.quit()
        break
```

Then I start to code it's working, but I can't see bullet image. Interestingly no error is produced. Can someone please help me. İ am so new to this. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

The bullet is not being drawn to the screen because `Sprite` objects only draw their internal `sprite.image` at the location in `sprite.rect`.  The player image is in `Player.image`, the bullet is in `Player.image2`.  Pygame.Sprite doesn't know anything about `image2`, and ignores it.

You could implement your own `Player.draw()` that blits both the images.  But the best solution is to separate the bullet out into it's own class:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image = pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.velocity    = 1

    def update( self ):
        x, y = self.rect.center    # get current position
        y -= self.velocity         # move up (negative-Y is up)
        if ( y < 0 ):
            self.kill()            # went off top of screen
        else:
            self.rect.center = ( x, y )


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('warship.png').convert()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH/2
        self.rect.bottom  = HEIGHT - 50
        self.speedx       = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 4
        elif keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            # Create a new bullet just above the player
            global all_bullets_group
            x, y = self.rect.center
            new_bullet = Bullet( x, y-5 )
            all_bullets_group.add( new_bullet )  

        [...]
```

Comment: thanks for interest friend. But now i take this error what should i do if you can help?           ('add() argument after * must be an iterable, not float')

Comment: And İ can't understand all_bullets_group

Comment: @Softwareprogrammer94 - `all_bullets_group` would be a PyGame Sprite Group - See: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group